# The products are not deleting from the shopping cart after ordering in python-django

Tags: python, django, cart

I am trying to make an e-commerce website. There is 1 problem which has been very hard to fix. The problem:
After ordering, products are supposed to be deleted from the shopping cart. But it is not working. There are no syntaxis errors but there is still products remaining after ordering.

Here is the part my views.py for it:

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    session = request.session
    cart = session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
    if cart is not None:
        del session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
else:
    customer = request.user.customer
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
        customer=customer, complete=False)

    order_products = OrderProduct.objects.filter(order=order)
    if order_products:
        order_product = order_products[0]
    else:
        order_product = OrderProduct.objects.create(order=order)

    order.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Заказ успешно оформлен. Проверьте свою электронную почту!!!')
    session = request.session
    cart = session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
    if cart is not None:
        del session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
        session.modified = True

return redirect('product_list')
```

I really hope someone can help me, please.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem that you're checking if cart is empty or not after your made an order as I understood `messages.success`

You don't actually need `if cart is not None:

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    session = request.session
    del session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
else:
    customer = request.user.customer
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
        customer=customer, complete=False)

    order_products = OrderProduct.objects.filter(order=order)
    if order_products:
        order_product = order_products[0]
    else:
        order_product = OrderProduct.objects.create(order=order)

    order.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Заказ успешно оформлен. Проверьте свою электронную почту!!!')
    session = request.session
    del session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
    session.modified = True

return redirect('product_list')
```

Comment: The codes you gave are ending up with errors. When I used 1st one I got (KeyError: 'cart'
Internal Server Error: /process/) error. And if I use the 2nd one I get (TypeError at /process/
'NoneType' object does not support item deletion) this error.

Comment: can you give the right answers pls

Comment: This is not the answer

Comment: I will change my answer and you can try it

Comment: let me know if its not working

Comment: I used it. It is not making errors this time. But there are still products in cart after ordering. It is when used is authenticated!

Comment: mb change from ```session = request.session``` to ```session = request```

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work

Comment: hey, I changed from `session = request.session` to `session = request` but it didn't work. there are still products in the cart. what should I do